# How to tell to a C++/Cli assembly to use any version of a reference

Tags: reference, c++-cli, versioning, .net-assembly

I have a C++/CLI assembly that references a C# assembly. I want that the C++/CLI uses any version of that reference. To do this in C# I use the SpecificVersion tag and I remove the version information.

In C++/CLI there is no SpecificVersion tag and looks liek removing the version information manually from the vcproj file is not enougth (I get FileLoadExceptions because it can't find the specific assembly version it was compiled with).

Any help will be great.

Thanks!

Working with VS2008 here